# Facebook API Python - Likes Per Month?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an application that will get a user's "likes per month" on Facebook. I've never worked with the Facebook API and I can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to do what I'm trying to do.

For example, [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) has the URL that will allow me to access the JSON data for the user's wall. That's cool and all, but how do I get that information programmatically and in the application? I have the basic application set up on heroku, and I'll be working with that.

Answer (score 1):

Call `/me/posts`, go through the paginated data and set conditionals to store likes based on the `created_time`.

Though all of this can get skewed if someone went back through old posts and started liking them. So it all depends on how you want to define likes per month

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

You could start by using a simple library like facepy

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI('your_access_token_goes_here')
pages = graph.get("me/posts", page=True)
for page in pages:
    // do something with page["data"] like drop the likes in a month array
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not too late but you could implement the following function:

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI('your_access_token_goes_here')
pages = graph.get("me/posts", page=True)
getLikes(pages['posts']['data'])
def getLikes(this):
"""
 Params- Takes in a page full of posts in the format- Eg. pages['posts']['data']
 Returns- Total number of likes for each post and created_time of each post

"""
    tli = []
    ti = []
    for i in this:
        r = graph.get("/"+i['id']+"/likes?limit=200")
        li = []
        ti.append(i['created_time'])
        for j in r['data']:  #goes into each posts to get list of likes
            li.append(j['name'])        
        tli.append(len(li))
    return tli,ti       ## this returns the total no of likes and corresponding created_time
```